# Getting a component by it's Generic Type

Tags: java, generics, search, components

What I'm trying to do is create a method that allows a user to search through a list of *GameComponents* to find a GameComponent of whatever class they passed in.

I'm at a total loss on how to do this. Any Ideas?

This is what I've tried so far. I've tried a lot of different ways to do it but I keep getting *classDude* cannot be resolved to a type. Thanks in advance.

```
public GameComponent<?> getComponentOfType(Class<Object> classDude)
    {

        for(GameComponent<?> gC : mComponentList)
        {
            if(gC instanceof classDude)
            {

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
public <T extends GameComponent<?>> T getComponentOfType(Class<T> classDude)
{
    for(GameComponent<?> gC : components)
    {
        if(classDude.isInstance(gC))
        {
            return classDude.cast(gC);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Or without making it generic:

```
public GameComponent<?> getComponentOfType(Class<?> classDude)
{
    for(GameComponent<?> gC : components)
    {
        if(classDude.isInstance(gC))
        {
            return (GameComponent<?>) classDude.cast(gC);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In other words, what you were missing were the [`Class.isInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`Class.cast`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) methods.

Comment: If I wanted the function itself to look like this how would I go about it:

Comment: getComponent<TextureComponent>();

Comment: @user1159418: You can't - that's simply not how you invoke generic methods in Java, and you *have* to provide the class, otherwise type erasure hits you. You can use `getComponent(TextureComponent.class)` though.